# If exist does not work anymore in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, exists

i have a problem with a batch. It scans folders for new pdf files, print, move and delete them. It worked fine until it suddenly stopped without an error. If i type it manually into the cmd it calls "file path does not exist", but it's the correct path. I don't have any clue, maybe some can help or have the same issue.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
@echo off

:pdfprint

echo Checkin Druck - bitte offen lassen

IF EXIST *.pdf for %%p in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\eRechnung\signed\*.pdf") do ( start /b "Print" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /t "%%p"

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10

%windir%\system32\taskkill.exe /F /IM AcroRd32.exe

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5

xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\eRechnung\signed\*.pdf" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Desktop\backup\"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2
move "%%p" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Documents\Belegtransfer\9860-11206\Rechnungsausgang\"
IF EXIST *.pdf for %%p in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\eRechnung\signed\*.pdf") do DEL *.pdf

)
IF EXIST *.pdf for %%p in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf") do ( start /b "Print" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /t "%%p"

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10

%windir%\system32\taskkill.exe /F /IM AcroRd32.exe

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5
xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Desktop\backup\"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2
move "%%p" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Documents\Belegtransfer\9860-11206\Rechnungsausgang\"
IF EXIST *.pdf for %%p in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf") do DEL *.pdf

)

goto :pdfprint
```

Comment: remove `@echo off` and launch the file from cmd.exe and simply see which path fails.

Comment: remove @echo off as Gerhard says. Also add echo commands throughout like `echo step1` , `echo step2` in order to see where if fails.

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos why bother adding more echo's? Just remove `@echo off` run the file and it will give the error directly after the failing path.

Comment: thank you for your comment. It's ridiculous, no path fails, runs through properly. It just don't print, move, copy the file

Comment: @DarioBuchholz Make sure, scroll through the entire console screen and see. If you have a path fail with echo off, it will be there with it on.

Comment: What is the exact error ... exact word for word.

Comment: I ran a modified version of his script, and see that the error could be caused by the move command. The move command, can produce this error, so he should check that the following folder exists: 'Rechnungsausgang'

Comment: C:\Users\Textilpflege>C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf") do (
The system can not find the path specified.

C:\Users\Textilpflege>xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Desktop\backup\"
file *.pdf not found
0 file(s) copied


C:\Users\Textilpflege>move "%%p" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Documents\Belegtransfer\9860-11206\Rechnungsausgang\"
The system can not find the stated file.

Comment: C:\Users\Textilpflege>if exist *.pdf for %%p in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf") do DEL *.pdf
"%%p" can not be processed syntactically at this point.

Comment: all the folders are existing and the paths are correct. i checked it again, still correct. Thank you @MenelaosBakopoulos good idea

Comment: Are you sure that this folder exists? `C:\Users\Textilpflege\Documents\Belegtransfer\9860-11206\Rechnungsausgang` ? Can you open explorer with that path?

Comment: You not need the `IF EXIST *.pdf` command at all. The `for %%p in ("...\*.pdf")` one process _existent_ files. If files not exists, process nothing...

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos yes i'm sure. I can open the copied link in the explorer

Comment: @Aacini yes, but there are pdf files in the folder

Comment: Excuse me? Do you read what I wrote? Just remove the `IF` command!

Comment: @Aacini Excuse me, seem like i had a lack of attention. Good point, there is no need for the if exist command. I'll give it a try

Comment: You get an error `"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle*.pdf` not found? is your code different in the actual script than in this code? the attched code does not have any `Poststelle*.pdf` without the backslash as in this example `"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard i translate it from german into english. I made a mistake while while copying. the correct output was 
    "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf"

Comment: ok, so the pdf file name is `Poststelle*.pdf` where * contains other text? or is `Postelle` a directory? because that will highlight the issue and change the below answer drastically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me modify the script with some changes. Firstly, I am unsure of why you want to check if files exist locally, then do  a for delete on another dir. Also, let's swop out `ping` for `timeout`

```
@echo off
:pdfprint
echo Checkin Druck - bitte offen lassen

for %%a in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\eRechnung\signed\*.pdf") do (
    start /b "Print" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /t "%%a"
    timeout 10
    %windir%\system32\taskkill.exe /F /IM AcroRd32.exe
    timeout 5
    xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\eRechnung\signed\*.pdf" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Desktop\backup\"
    timeout 2
    move "%%a" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Documents\Belegtransfer\9860-11206\Rechnungsausgang\"
    del "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\eRechnung\signed\*.pdf"
 )
for %%d in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf") do (
    start /b "Print" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /t "%%d"
    timeout 5
    %windir%\system32\taskkill.exe /F /IM AcroRd32.exe
    timeout 5
    xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Desktop\backup\"
    timeout 2
    move "%%d" "C:\Users\Textilpflege\Documents\Belegtransfer\9860-11206\Rechnungsausgang\"
    del "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\Poststelle\*.pdf"
 )
goto :pdfprint
```

Problems!

1. too many for loops where not needed. You do `for %%p in (path\to\*.pdf) del *.pdf` so effectively saying, for each `pdf`, delete all `pdf`'s. Simply do a `del path\*.pdf` without the unwanted for loops.
2. You assign the same token value `%%p` to 2 for loops, instead, I added `%%a` and `%%d`
3. The if exist statements are useless, as you check if exist locally *.pdf, but delete in another folder.

Comment: for %%p in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Lexware\bueroeasy\Daten\eRechnung\signed\*.pdf") do ( start /b "Print" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /t "%%p"
"%%p" can not be processed syntactically at this point.

Comment: Because in this folder the pdf appear as soon as they are created, they should not be stored there because they have to be further processed

Comment: signed and Poststelle are folders

Comment: i don't know why but after signed there is a slash. If i write a comment here it disappear

Comment: it's working now. Great thanks. Is the query necessary? What the heck was the problem?

Comment: without it only minimaize, so i killed it... :)